# Programmatically Removing Garbage Text from Excel File in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, binary, filestream

I have an Excel file that downloads automatically, but for some reason the binary XLS file contains some garbage HTML text at the end of it.

When opening the file in the Excel application, it shows a warning but proceeding will automatically remove the garbage HTML text.

However, I need to open the file programmatically. When doing so via

```
Dim wb As Workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFileName)
```

It throws:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Any advice on how to either:

a) Get Excel to perform a similar action as if I manually opened it and remove the garbage HTML automatically.   NOTE: Tried setting the XlCorruptLoad.xlRepairFile parameter and it didn't work.

OR 
b) Remove the garbage text from the XLS binary file (FileStream?) and resave it before attempting to open the file with the code mentioned above.

The garbage html always comes at the very end of the file and starts with

Answer (score 1):

Where are you downloading the file from? My guess is that the server is written in ASP.NET, and has just failed to include a call to `Response.End()` after writing the Excel file to the response. If you're responsible for the server, that's definitely where you should fix it.

Comment: Not my server, and I don't think it is ASP.NET...  I'll notify them of the issue and see if they fix it on their end...  But so far the question is still open.